# Using the Decorator Pattern to Conditionally Replace Behaviour Instead of Extending

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns, polymorphism, decorator

Initially I had this structure:

```
interface IFileBackup
{
    void Backup();
}

class BackUpMechanism1 : IFileBackup
{
    void Backup()
    {
        //Back it up
    }
}

class BackUpMechanism2 : IFileBackup
{
    void Backup()
    {
        //Back it up in another way
    }
}

class Client 
{
    //Instantiation of both mechanisms
    //

    try
    {
        backUpMechanism1.Backup();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        backupMechanism2.Backup();
    }
}
```

I was told that this was not a very clean design and to redesign it using the decorator pattern. The client should not know about the two back up mechanisms but just call backup and then the first mechanism should try to back up the file and if that fails then use mechanism 2. However I don't understand how to use the decorator pattern because from my understanding it extends functionality but doesn't replace functionality - which is what I want... How do I archive that? I have tried the following:

```
interface IFileBackup
{
    void Backup();
}

class BackupMechanism1 : IFileBackup
{
    public void Backup()
    {
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Trying to back up to the cloud...");
            throw new Exception();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Oops that failed. We need to back up locally instead...");
        }

    }
}

class BackupMechanism2 : IFileBackup
{
    IFileBackup _fileBackup;
    public BackupMechanism2(IFileBackup fileBackup)
    {
        _filebackup = fileBackup;
    }

    public void Backup()
    {
        //All examples I have seen does this. But doesn't make sense in my case?
        _fileBackup.Backup();

        Console.WriteLine("Backing up locally");
    }
}

//The client does not care about how the backup is done
class Client
{
    static void Main()
    {
        //This is not right, but not sure what I should do in the client.
        BackupMechanism2 localBackup = new BackupMechanism2(new BackupMechanism1());
        localBackup.Backup();

        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

So essentially what I want to achieve is to have two backup mechanisms. Have the client just say backup I don't care how. Let the first mechanism try it's backup method if that fails then try the second method. I'm trying to use the decorator pattern to extend(replace) the backup behaviour of the first mechanism if it fails. I'm struggling to come up with a design that makes sense.

Comment: All you need to do is wrap `_fileBackup.Backup();` in your try/catch (I'd personally make `Backup()` return a `bool` instead of using exceptions as flow control) and in the catch try fallback method. Just like you have in the first snippet. The first backup mechanism shouldn't be trying to do the fallback method. It shouldn't even be aware that there is a fallback method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very clean approach of implementing this would be adding a composite `IFileBackup` taking an array of `IFileBackup` objects, and trying them one by one until a working solution is found:

```
class CompositeBackup {
    private readonly IFileBackup[] chain;
    public CompositeBackup(params IFileBackup[] chain) {
        this.chain = chain.ToArray();
    }
    public void Backup() {
        foreach (var backup in chain) {
            try {
                backup.Backup();
                return;
            } catch {
                continue;
            }
        }
        throw new InvalidOperationException();
    }
}
```

Now the client simply does this:

```
IFileBackup backup = new CompositeBackup(
    new BackupMechanism1()
,   new BackupMechanism2()
);
backup.Backup();
```

If you later decide to add `BackupMechanism3` and `BackupMechanism4`, the user would need to add another object to the chain of backups. The rest of the code would remain unchanged. In addition, backup mechanisms themselves would remain unaware of other mechanisms' existence, which also simplifies the code.

Comment: Interesting. How would this work with DI then? I would simply inject the `CompositeBackup` into the client and then invoke `Backup` on the injected instance? Then the backup mechanisms can be added in the DI registeration module?

Comment: I'm just thinking that if I put it in the DI setup then this is kind of "hidden" to someone reading the code no? Would it be better to inject the backup mechanisms into the client and then instantiating the composite backup from there? That would add some "noise" to the client though, as ideally the client shouldn't care. What do you think?

Comment: @DSF Correct, if you put it in the DI, it's no longer in code, which is usually a good thing, because it adds flexibility to your system: this is similar to making something configurable rather than hard-coding it.

Comment: The problem with this approach (which is a hybrid of Chain of Responsibility Pattern and Strategy Pattern) is that adding new backup mechanisms will require a re-compilation. Also, this design is **not** clean, it uses Exceptions to determine the flow of the program

Comment: @BillRichards Adding new implementations of `IFileBackup` would require recompiling no matter what.

Comment: Not at all. If the application is Bootstrapped with a DI container and the plumbing put in place to dynamically load assemblies (which is not much work) then a purely interface driven implementation of the strategy pattern would require zero re-compilation. Have a look at the full solution I posted in my answer for an idea of what I'm talking about -I've not put any of the dynamic loading/registration in that example, but you should get the idea of how the concept can be realized..

Comment: @BillRichards You can't add a new implementation of `IFileBackup` without compiling that implementation. The approach is DI-friendly - all you need to do is constructing `CompositeBackup` through a configuration.

Comment: Compiling a new assembly is **not** recompilation. And DI composition via configuration is an anti-pattern. Best practice for IoC is Configuration in code. Check out the info on the SimpleInjector documentation for a good discussion.

Comment: @BillRichards Apart from compiling a new assembly, the approach described above can be used without recompilation, too.

Answer (score 1):

The decorator pattern, in this case, can be used to provide fallback implementations. You can find plenty of obvious examples in the .Net streams implementation.

So with that in mind, your code should look something like this:

```
class abstract BaseFileBackup
{
  internal BaseFileBackup Fallback;
  internal BaseFileBackup(BaseFileBackup fallback) { Fallback = fallback; }
  internal BaseFileBackup() { }

  internal abstract void DoBackupWork();

  internal void Backup()
  {
    try { DoBackupWork(); }
    catch { if(Fallback != null) Fallback.Backup(); else throw; }
  }
}

class BackUpMechanism1 : BaseFileBackup
{
    internal BackUpMechanism1 (BaseFileBackup fallback): base(fallback) {}
    internal BackUpMechanism1 (): base() {}

    internal void DoBackupWork()
    {
        //Back it up
    }
}

class BackUpMechanism2 : BaseFileBackup
{
    internal BackUpMechanism2 (BaseFileBackup fallback): base(fallback) {}
    internal BackUpMechanism2 (): base() {}

    internal void DoBackupWork()
    {
        //Back it up in another way
    }
}

// and to call it
class Client
{
    static void Main()=>
        new BackupMechanism2(new BackupMechanism1()).Backup();
}
```

Comment: Do you mind linking to an example in the Stream source code? I would love to see a real world usuage of this pattern

Comment: You see it every time you do something like `new BufferedStream(new FileStream(@"file.txt"), 10*1024*1024)` or `new StreamWriter(new MemoryStream())`, where each additional stream in the chain gets assigned to the parent's `BaseStream` property and accessed internally through it.

Answer (score 1):

Decorator Pattern is the WRONG choice in this scenario.

The problem that  you are dealing with here is

- under condition x call one method
- under condition y call a different method
- ...

This is the precondition for the Strategy Pattern, and your initial solution was quite close to that. The problem in my mind is that you are using an Exception to determine the program flow, which is a BAD thing to do: exceptions cost stack space, and they should only be thrown under EXCEPTIONAL circumstances. Whereas in your case, it is expected that a given strategy will not work

```
IFileBackupStrategy 
{
    bool Backup(File fileToBackup);
}

IFileBackupContext
{
    File ForBackup { set; }
    bool Backup();
}

class CloudBackUp : IFileBackupStrategy 
{
    private bool _success;

    public bool Backup(File fileToBackup) 
    {
        // code to do backup omitted 
        // it will set the value of _success to false if it was unsuccessful

        return _success;
    }
}   

class LocalBackUp : IFileBackupStrategy 
{
    private bool _success;

    public bool Backup(File fileToBackup) 
    {
        // code to do backup omitted
        // it will set the value of _success to false if it was unsuccessful

        return _success;
    }
}

public class FileBackupContext : IFileBackupContext
{
    private IEnumerable<IFileBackupStrategy> _backupStrategies
    public Context(IEnumerable<IFileBackupStrategy> backupStrategies)
        => _backupStrategies = backupStrategies;

    public File ForBackup { set; private get; }

    public bool Backup()
    {
        bool successFlag;

        foreach(var strategy in _backupStrategies)
        {
            successFlag = strategy.Backup(ForBackup);
            if(successFlag) break;
        }

        return successFlag;
    }
}
```

In this case, all that the client needs to be aware of is the IFileBackupContext, and not the strategy employed to do the saving.

```
public class MyBackupClient
{
    private IFileBackupContext _context;

    public MyBackupClient(IFileBackupContext context) => _context = context;

    void SomeMethodThatInvokesBackingUp()
    {
        _context.ForBackup = new File(/* */);

        if(!_context.Backup())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Failed to backup  the file");
        }
    }
}
```

The beauty of this design is that you can add more IFileBackupStrategy implementations, register them with your DI Container and voila they are instantly available to the client without a single code change or the need for re-compilation (though that will ultimately depend upon how you are populating your DI Container)

The decorator pattern is a method of adhering to the O principle in SOLID: which is

> Open for extension and closed for modification

This means that you would use the decorator pattern to *decorate* an **existing** class, one that should not be changed and yet does not exhibit the behaviour required. The clue is in the name of the pattern: **Decorator** *adds* something, it does not *change* anything.

The *Decorator Pattern* is a **Structural Pattern**, whereas the *Strategy Pattern*, and what you are looking for, is a **Behavioural Pattern**

This example can be extended of course to report back the strategy which was ultimately employed, and also (if required) any reasoning for why alternate strategies were not.

> **Edited: in response to Blindy's comment below**. Here is the paradigm for the decorator pattern, which should demonstrate how it is not the correct pattern for this problem:

```
 class Image 
 {
    void Render() { /*  */ }
 }

 class FramedImage : Image 
 { 
    private Image _originalImage;
    public FramedImage(Image original) => _originalImage = original;

    new public void Render()
    {
        /* code to render a frame */
        _originalImage.Render();
    }
 }

Image originalImage = new Image();
Image framedImage = new FramedImage(originalImage);

Image toRender = originalImage;
toRender.Render() // Renders the original image

toRender = framedImage;
toRender.Render(); // Renders the original image in a frame
```

It should be observed that there is no ***need*** to assign each Image to the toRender variable, that is done solely to demonstrate that a decorator ***is a*** decorated.

As you can see from this example, the decorator pattern adds behaviour, **and it also invokes the decorated item's behaviour**.

> **Edited: Further to the question posed by DSF below**. Here is the full listing for a console app demonstrating how to achieve this using Unity 5.8.6

The code takes advantage of the new Tuple from C# 7.0.
I've just used some random number generation to determine whether or not each strategy implementation succeeds in performing its task.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using Unity;
using Unity.Injection;

namespace StrategyPattern
{
   public interface IFileBackupContext
   {
      FileStream ForBackup { set; }
      (bool success, string strategy) Backup();
   }

   public interface IFileBackupStrategy 
   {
      (bool success, string name) Backup(FileStream fileToBackup);
   }

   internal class LocalBackUp : IFileBackupStrategy
   {
      private bool _success = false;

      public (bool success, string name) Backup(FileStream fileToBackup)
      {
         // code to do backup omitted
         var random = new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);
         _success = (random.Next() % 3) == 0;
         if(_success) fileToBackup.Close();
         // it will set the value of _success to false if it was unsuccessful
         return (_success, "LocalBackUp");
      }
   }

   internal class CloudBackUp : IFileBackupStrategy
   {
      private bool _success = false;

      public (bool success, string name) Backup(FileStream fileToBackup)
      {
         // code to do backup omitted 
         var random = new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);
         _success = (random.Next() % 3) == 0;
         if (_success) fileToBackup.Close();
         // it will set the value of _success to false if it was unsuccessful

         fileToBackup.Close();
         return (_success, "CloudBackUp");
      }
   }

   public class FileBackupContext : IFileBackupContext
   {
      private readonly IEnumerable<IFileBackupStrategy> _backupStrategies;

      public FileBackupContext(IEnumerable<IFileBackupStrategy> backupStrategies)
         => _backupStrategies = backupStrategies;

      public FileStream ForBackup { set; private get; }

      public (bool success, string strategy) Backup()
      {
         foreach (var strategy in _backupStrategies)
         {
            var (success, name) = strategy.Backup(ForBackup);
            if (success) return (true, name);
         }

         return (false, "");
      }
   }

   public class MyBackupClient
   {
      private IFileBackupContext _context;

      public MyBackupClient(IFileBackupContext context) => _context = context;

      public void BackgUpMyFile()
      {
         _context.ForBackup = new FileStream("d:\\myfile", FileMode.OpenOrCreate);

         (bool success, string strategy) = _context.Backup();

         if (!success)
         {
            Console.WriteLine("Failed to backup  the file");
            return;
         }

         Console.WriteLine($"File backed up using [{strategy}] strategy");
      }
   }

   public class Bootstrap
   {
      private readonly IUnityContainer _container;
      public Bootstrap()
      {
         _container = new UnityContainer();


         _container.RegisterType<IFileBackupContext, FileBackupContext>();
         _container.RegisterType<IFileBackupStrategy, LocalBackUp>("local");
         _container.RegisterType<IFileBackupStrategy, CloudBackUp>("cloud");
         _container.RegisterType<MyBackupClient>();

         _container.RegisterType<Func<IEnumerable<IFileBackupStrategy>>>(new InjectionFactory(c =>
            new Func<IEnumerable<IFileBackupStrategy>>(() =>
               new[]
               {
                  c.Resolve<IFileBackupStrategy>("local"),
                  c.Resolve<IFileBackupStrategy>("cloud")
               }
            )));
      }

      public MyBackupClient GetClient() => _container.Resolve<MyBackupClient>();
   }

   class Program
   {
      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
         Console.WriteLine("Press ESC to quit ...");
         Console.WriteLine("Press any other key to try again.");
         Console.WriteLine();
         var client = new Bootstrap().GetClient();
         do
         {
            client.BackgUpMyFile();
         } while (Console.ReadKey().Key != ConsoleKey.Escape);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: You're not wrong that your implementation is also solid (no pun intended), but it could be argued that you're *extending* one backup process with additional fallback backup processes, without changing individual ones.

Comment: Agreed @Blindy, it could be argued that we are extending the backup *process*. 

However, it is good to think of the following example as a case for implementing the Decorator Pattern:

We have an image class which is used in several places throughout our application.
Some part of the application renders this image.
On the page/form we are currently creating we want the image to have a frame.
We can't change the image because other places in the application do not want or need the frame.

Comment: I think a better analogy would be providing fallback images for different conditions (screen reader, lower resolution phones, etc) in addition to your main image, which in HTML5 is done with a `<picture>` tag that can contain multiple `<img>` tags. Since the "host" tag is a different one than its children, it would match your strategy pattern.

Comment: Fall-back images for different conditions is **_not_** decoration by any stretch of the imagination. It is, as you have identified an implementation of the Strategy Pattern. The analogy I gave was for the decorator pattern.

Comment: Interesting solution. Using DI, how would you give the backup strategies to the context class? This would also have to be done in the DI registration module like @dasblinkenlight's solution ? Would you be able to guarentee order in this case, as I want the strategies to be "tried" in a specific order?

Comment: Populating your container and injecting dependencies is entirely dependent upon your implementation of choice (Unity, nInject, SimpleInject, etc).  I would expect you to be able to use automatic registration in a modern DI Container (for your IFileBackupStrategy implementations), it is then a matter of building the IEnumerable<IFileBackupStrategy> and getting that registered with your container. The comments section is far to short a space to provide such an answer I'm afraid, but yes you could swap the IEnumerable<T> for an OrderedList<T> or you could carefully construct your enumeration, etc